# Oracle apex get interactive report row count

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5

Inquiring if there is any way to get the row count of an interactive report and save the value into an item.

I was trying other solutions from oracle forums but none worked for me.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that I know:

1. Change the IR region Pagination to -> **Row Ranges X to Y of Z** then use the below JavaScript code. Put the below code in JavaScript -> **Exceute When Page Loads** section.

```
var str = $("#YOUR_REGION_STATIC_ID .a-IRR-pagination-label").text();
var totalCount = str.charAt(str.length-1);
$s('YOUR_PAGE_ITEM_NAME',totalCount);
```

If the pagination should be hidden and if the item must be contain the total count then put the below code in JavaScript -> **Exceute When Page Loads** section to hide the pagination.

```
$('#YOUR_REGION_STATIC_ID .a-IRR-paginationWrap').css('display','none');
```

**Disclaimer: The above solution does not work if the IR Pagination Type is not Row Ranges X to Y of Z**

2. The easiest way is to create a Before/After Header computation for the page item and get the count using your report query.